# Movie math, real or not? (Ghost busters trailer)

Tags: recreational-mathematics, proof-explanation

I was watching the ghost busters trailer, and I stopped on a frame containing 'quantum physics'. I wonder if all of this is meaningful math, or some of it is complete gibberish, to look smart.

I see we have seemingly the special unitary group $SU(n)$ mapping to what seems to be $N^2-1$ which seems like gibberish to me for starters.

[Relevant image. 1:06 from the trailer.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xviCx.jpg)

---

Perhaps it all is real math, afterall, we have all seen 'It's my turn' by Jill Clayburgh.

Comment: you might want to post this to the physics stackexchange as well; they tend to have some strange Lie gorup/algebra notation, especially where QFT is involved.

Comment: @Omnomnomnom I'd say instead.

Comment: Here is a [post at Physics.SE](http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/151139/why-do-gauge-bosons-leptoquarks-not-mediate-proton-decay-in-the-pati-salam-model/220108) that relates to the mention of proton decay, gauge bosons, and special unitary group.  That said, there seems to be either math errors or omissions in the steps immediately above that whiteboard section.

Comment: If she's supposed to be trying to figure something out, that gives the set designer some leeway. Any mathematical mistake could be explained away as showing that the character has not figured out the problem. However, it does look like they got a bona fide science consultant: http://thequantumtunnel.com/interview-physicist-ghostbusters-proton-pack/ How much the screenwriters, producers, etc., listen to him, I don't know.